# Can't open prototxt

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, face-detection

```
   protoPath = os.path.sep.join([r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face recognitio\face_detection_model", 
    "deploy.prototxt.txt"])
    modelPath = os.path.sep.join([r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognitio\face_detection_model",
        "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
    detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)
```

this is the code but i tried everything and is still can't open it

```
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognitio\face_detection_model\deploy.prototxt.txt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile
```

i did't find anything useful

Comment: Does the file `C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognitio\face_detection_model\deploy.prototxt.txt` actually exist?

Comment: yes,i tried it without .txt and doesn't work

Comment: can you open this file in text editor? Is this path correct? Maybe Windows doesn't display real extension and it has something more than only `.txt`. You could also check `print( os.listdir(r"C:\Users\osama\Desktop\opencv-face-recognitio\face_detection_model\") )`

Comment: no i can't open it in text editor ,but the path correct

Comment: i tried your code but i have an error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\osama\\Desktop\\opencv-face-recognitio\\face_detection_model\\deploy.prototxt'

Comment: We cannot validate if the path is correct for you, its something you need to do, as you have the information in front of you. Did you notice that the work recognition is misspelled as recognitio?

Comment: thank you so mush , i can't tell you how mush i sorry for your time

Comment: So it was just the misspelled word?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: am using the same method above, with correct spellings, but getting the error again.
Am running in on Windows10, android studio.
Any help??

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck on this for days.
This [solution on github](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/144) worked for me finally.

```
from os.path import dirname, join

protoPath = join(dirname(__file__), "deploy.prototxt")
modelPath = join(dirname(__file__), "openCVs_facedetector")
```

os: windows10